# Protecting Wordpress login page

Tags: login, security

How can i do this:

Whenever visitors open the login page (wp-login.php), they will be redirected to the mainpage. Only the admin (me) can view the page to login.

I am doing this to protect my wp sites. Is there any better way to protect WP login page?

Answer (score 2):

You can make it so no one can register by clicking off "Anyone can register" in your Admin.

Furthermore, you can choose a really good password, install a login lockdown plugin and enable logins over https. In most cases this is secure enough.

If your really paranoid you can allow access to only your IP by using .htaccess.

```
<Files wp-login.php>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 11.11.111.111 (your IP)
</Files>
```

To do a re-direct you can try something like this in your .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^127\.0\.0\.1 (Your IP)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wp-login\.php$ 
RewriteRule .* http://www.yourhomepage.com [R=403,L]
# 403 is a "forbidden", you can change this to another status code
```

Comment: Actually, i get this idea after i read Dreamhost newsletter. They mention their new website now is built on WP. So i try to put /wp-login.php or /wp-admin at the end of their website's URL but what happen is i am redirected to the mainpage.

This is what i want to do. Somehow i think only the admin know what is the right URL to login to the WP address. How to achieve this?

Comment: Updated my answer for a redirect, but in all honestly if you don't know how to do this then you probably don't need to do this. Install a login lockdown plugin instead, who cares if people can reach the login page...

Comment: the plugin is not updated

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/limit-login-attempts/  Just because a plugin is not up to date does not necessarily mean it does not work.